# Angular bound properties not available during ViewChild method call

Tags: angular, binding, viewchild

I have an Angular2 view that calls a method on a child component to initialise it during the view load. The child component is bound to a property on the parent that I want to access during the method call; however, for some reason, it is not populated until after the call is complete. [This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SxxzkWcLRaR95yvq8Q0u?p=preview) demonstrates the issue.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('child')
  child: ChildComponent;

  message: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = "Set by parent";
    this.child.onParentInvoke();
  }
}

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  message: string;
  callProperty: string;

  onParentInvoke() {
    //I want the message property to be populated here
    this.callProperty = this.message;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Parent template:

```
<div>This is parent</div>
<div>Message: {{message}}</div>
<child #child [message]="message"></child>
```

Child template:

```
<div>This is child</div>
<div>Message during method call: {{callProperty}}</div>
<div>Message: {{message}}</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why the property is not bound at this stage, and what I can do to ensure that it is populated during the method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Solution following Paul Taylor comment:

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('child')
  child: ChildComponent;

  message: string;

  constructor(
      private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.message = "Set by parent";
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    this.child.onParentInvoke();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve it (and I did put the detectChanges() call before the line in which I cache the bound property value).

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure it would... 
Couldn't it has something to do with the lack of constructor in your components?

Comment: Discovered that if I put the ChangeDetectorRef in the Parent component and call detectChanges() before invoking `this.child.onParentInvoke()`, it works. If you update the post, I'll give you the credit.

Comment: How about removing the initial suggestion for ChildComponent for clarity?